# Should I create an activity for each screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-2.3-gingerbread

I will start with an example... If you go to *Settings > Applications > Manage applications*, a new screen will open with a list of the installed applications: if you click on any application of the list, it will open a new screen containing information about the application.

Well, some settings of my application must be managed through a list, and this list should behave like the above example. I have already created a `PreferenceActivity` with some categories, each of which has some items: when I click on one of these items, I would like it to open a new screen where the new data is placed on a list, just like the list of the applications of the above example. Moreover, when I click on any entry of this list, it will open a new screen in order to set some data.

How should I proceed? Should I create an activity for each screen?

Comment: Once you get a feel for this you should also look at fragments, they are supported in older versions of the OS via the support library so that for instance 2.3 can use the single activity model, but can also take advantage of fragments in 3.0+  Don't confuse yourself right now :-) but do look at it when it all starts to gel

Comment: made the edit like I promised!

Answer (score 5):

Android was created this way, according to the documentation "An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do.", so yes, you should have an activity for each screen.
This changed a little with Honeycomb with the introduction of Fragments, but if you're not developing for tablets you should keep the one page, one activity mindset on Android.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you have each activity call by another, the caller is pushed onto a stack (unless the calling activity ask's to be removed) and goes dormant until it returns

Basically you create an Intent in Activity A to start Activity B, you can pass data by using startActivityForResult with extras in the intents Example: [How to pass data between activities](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/)

When you press the back button then that previous activity becomes active again and the result handler you set up can get any return data.

You might also look at fragments in the support API if you want to provide tablet support that looks and behaves better.

Answer (score 2):

That is propably the best way to do it, at least if you're not working on a wizard style activity.

Use a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) to show your list, and pass data to and from this activity using [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to implement this at work, I don't remember right now in the head how I implemented it, was long time ago. If nobody has a good answer for you I will post it tomorrow, however: I remember putting a Preference, which will act as a button, then I added a preferenceClickListener in order to open a new PreferenceScreen on click.
But like I said, I'll post it for you tomorrow if you don't get a satisified answer.

Good luck!

UPDATE:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Personal"
    android:key="personal_category">
    <Preference
        android:key="birth"
        android:title="Birth"
        android:summary="Choose your birthday"/> 
    <PreferenceScreen 
        android:key="height_imp"
        android:title="Height"
        android:summary="Enter your height">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="foot"
            android:title="Foot" 
            android:summary="foot"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:dialogTitle="Foot"/>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="inch"
            android:title="Inch" 
            android:summary="inch"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:dialogTitle="Inch"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="weight"
        android:title="Weight" 
        android:summary="Enter your weight"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:dialogTitle="Weight"/>    
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

That's it! When you click on it, it will take you to the second PreferenceScreen and so on, then finally when you need to customize your layout you'll need to open an Activity.
You could then use a Preference and add onPreferenceClick:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    if(preference == birth){
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Birth.class));
    }
    if(preference == height_imp){
        PreferenceScreen a = (PreferenceScreen) preference;
        a.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you need to change the background or something else with the preferenceScreen, then add a preferenceClickListener as well: `height_imp = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("height_imp");
        height_imp.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

See... if once the user wants to return from certain point to previous position... if you had created a seperate activity for each of them... the present activity will be popped off the stack... letting the previous activity to be displayed...If you are changing the content of the list for every new screen...instead of creating new activity... then it will be difficult for the user to come back... you should again and again change the content of adapter..
So I think.. creating seperate activity for each screen is better..( and  you can use same [any custom layout if you have]layout file for all activities..)